# Github actions not recognizing secret value during build

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, github-actions

I have a Spring boot application which has an api key. I have set this value up in my Github repo
under the secrets as follows.

```
EMAIL_API_KEY = 123
```

When I push my code, it starts building and fails during maven build with following error.

> Error creating bean restHelper. Could not resolve placeholder
> 'EMAIL_API_KEY' in value "${EMAIL_API_KEY}"

In Spring boot, I have the value as followins inside my application.properties file.

```
api_key=${EMAIL_API_KEY}
```

How do I reference this variable. Is secrets not the correct location?

I do not see the option to set environment variables and using secrets. Please advice. Thanks.

A more verbose error log.

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'emailController' defined in file
> [/../EmailController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through
> constructor parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'restHelper' defined in file
> [/../RestHelper.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation;
> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not
> resolve placeholder 'EMAIL_API_KEY' in value "${EMAIL_API_KEY}"

My Yaml file for GitHub Actions.

```
name: CI/CD Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'

jobs:

  test:
    name: Test - Units & Integrations
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11.0.4
      - name: Maven Package
        run: mvn -B clean package # FAILS AT THIS STEP
      - name: Maven Verify
        run: mvn -B clean verify
        
        # added this to test, same outcome.
        env:
          EMAIL_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_API_KEY }}
```

Comment: Does `EMAIL_API_KEY` appear under secrets in the repo ?

Comment: @fixxxer Yes it is under the correct repo's secrets.

Comment: Did you try adding the env variable under the specific job that is failing?

- name: Maven Package
        env: EMAIL_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_API_KEY }}
        run: mvn -B clean package

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thanks that actually did it. Is this a norm, having to repeat that variable all over the place? Coss I have a few more steps needing that same variable too.

Comment: As jobs run in different runners, those runners are in different machines. Each job runs in a fresh instance of the virtual environment specified by runs-on. It is not possible to share environment variables between machines.  They don’t support to share variables between jobs (yet)

However; there are some actions that allows to share datas between jobs using artifacts. You could eventually use it if it makes sense: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/share-jobs-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inform your environment variables for each job.

***Example:***

```
 - name: Maven Package 
     env: EMAIL_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_API_KEY }} 
     run: mvn -B clean package
```

***Explanation:***

As jobs run in different runners, those runners are in different machines. Each job runs in a fresh instance of the virtual environment specified by runs-on.

It is not possible to share environment variables between machines. Github actions don’t support to share variables between jobs (yet).

However, there are some actions that allows to share datas between jobs using artifacts. You could eventually use it if it makes sense: [github.com/marketplace/actions/share-jobs-data](http://github.com/marketplace/actions/share-jobs-data)